# HDMI eye diagram questions

Tags: hdmi

I recently got a eye diagram from one of the supplier which looks not quite the same as the other one I used to see.

[image: Eye diagram 1]

so from this I think this is a pass as it has plenty of margin from the Mask, but my question is about the amplitude of the eye, the way it exceed the top and bottom limit in an unusual way.

I was thinking about it has something to do with a booster, but any HDMI guru here have see eye diagram similar to this before can point me if it has something to do with the circuit of the HDMI connector?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of product is producing this and what is the intended purpose and receiver of the signal? It *might* be about preemphasis.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like pre-emphasis.  The idea is to pre-distort the signal before transmitting it down the cable so that the eye at the far end of the cable is more open.  If you check the pre-distorted eye at the transmitter, you'll likely see something like this with lots of overshoot.  If you check at the receiver after a decent length of cable, it should look more normal.

The idea is that cables will attenuate high frequency components and slow down/round off transitions.  Intentionally overshooting on the transmit end means that the system will tolerate more high frequency attenuation in the cable.